# Woocommerce remove attributes option used for variations

Tags: woocommerce, product-variations

I have a woocommerce with a lot of products and they have 6 attributes used for variations:

attribute_pa_color
attribute_pa_acabado
attribute_pa_textura
attribute_pa_material
attribute_pa_color_basico
attribute_pa_kintsugi

right now i'm going to use for variations just the attribute_pa_color, and not the others so i need to update all those attributes to "not used for variations".
I could do it manually going to each product and uncheking the used for variations checkbox but i have tons of products.

I'm trying to find it in the database with no luck. Is it possible to do it with code?

Comment: don't understand the negative points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create backup before doing anything
2. Place the following function in functions.php of your active theme.
   for some reason its bugging and cant wrap all as code. Its hooked to init event but you can change it to run how you want it. Tested and works. Also added commented way if you want to hide attribute too from being visible in product page.

   function tt_disable_attributes_as_variations() {

   ```
        $product_ids = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'any',
            'fields' => 'ids',
        ));

        // add the rest of attributes you want
        $attributes_to_update = array('pa_acabado', 'pa_textura'); 

        foreach ($product_ids as $product_id) {
            $product_attributes = get_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes', true);
            foreach ($attributes_to_update as $attribute_slug) {
                if (isset($product_attributes[$attribute_slug])) {
                    //Disable showing on product page
                    // $product_attributes[$attribute_slug]['is_visible'] = 0; 
                    //Disable being used as variation
                    $product_attributes[$attribute_slug]['is_variation'] = 0; 
                }
            }
            update_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes);
        }
    }

    add_action('init', 'tt_disable_attributes_as_variations');
   ```

Comment: Awesome!!! it works perfect!! you rock